# Integrating Third Party Ad Networks in MoPub

Tags: android, mopub

I am already successfully serving ads with admob but I thought, why use one ad network if you can use "all" of them. So here I am with mopub.

I really thought by integrating the mopub sdk I dont need to mess with other sdks again and just integrating the mopub sdk is all I really need.

But I am reading through [mopub's guide](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks) and I am not sure what to do now about the third party ad networks.

So I got a few questions:

1. Do I need to integrate all the third party SDK to be able to receive ads from other ad networks?
2. If the classes in extras / src / com / mopub / mobileads are already in the SDK why do I need to copy them over into my source?
3. And If I copy all the classes over, am I done with the integration or do I need to do something else in my code to make mopub use these specific classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MoPub has a few way of mediating ad networks.

There are

1. Server to Server (S2S) integrations in which nothing extra has to be included in the MoPub SDK. You only have to create an account on the network and include ids to serve the ads.
   The following networks are:

Greystripe 
Huntsmads 
Lifestreet 
MobFox 
Mojiva 
TapIt

2. Native Network integrations which require the 3rd-party SDKs to be included in your project, but for these MoPub had prebuilt adapters which can be found in the master branch of their GitHub in the [extras folder here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/tree/master/extras/src/com/mopub/mobileads)

These networks include:

AdMob 
iAd 
Millennial Media 
AdColony 
Chartboost 
Facebook 
InMobi 
Vungle

3. Custom Event integrations which are for integrations where you want to integrate with Javascript tags.

You do not need to integrate all of the ad networks. You can pick and choose which ones you would like to integrate.

Only the master branch of the MoPub SDK has all the ad network adapters in the SDK. The **MoPub Android Full SDK** does not include the network adapters, nor does the **MoPub Android Base SDK**. In these situations, you need to copy them to your source.

After successfully including everything in your project, you have to set up the ad networks in the **Network** tab in the MoPub web UI. Here, for each ad network integrated through adapter, you have to enter the specified IDs for your ads to serve.

Once the ad network is set up for each ad unit, you can manage everything in the **Segments** tab under the **Networks** tab. Here, after removing the **Status:Running** filter, you can click the drop down and set the eCPMs of the ad networks per ad unit to specify how you want your waterfall to be in the mediation (higher eCPMs are prioritized higher). From this point, the ad networks you have set will be included in the ad sources for the ad units you specified them for.

Comment: finally able to show apps in my startapp network by adding ecpm for each ad unit by removing 'Status:Running' filter in global segment. It hasn't shown ads yet but but it's a start. Mopub is probably the most complicated and confusing dashboard i have seen in ad networks. Mopub support is very disappointing just like google. Thanks Edward!

Comment: Is your s2s on mopub running properly?